# Best Approach For Updating Page from php

Tags: php, jquery, asynchronous

I have a script the processes about 100 rows of data within a foreach loop.  I would like to have a page that has a submit button and as the script successfully iterates it would append data from that row to a div on the page- giving some feedback to the user.  It's different than most of the examples Im seeing online in that the php script would be posting multiple times instead just once.  thanks for any input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make 2 calls to php from jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of HTTP, your best bet might be to use Ajax.

My thoughts would be to send an Ajax request to your script, and then once the script is done and sends the response, parse the response and put it into your div.